# Google deleted my developer account without warning or much explanation. What can I do?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, internet, software

I haven't received any prior warning in fact from Google and suddenly received the following message:

> This is a notification that your Google Play Publisher account has been terminated.
>
> REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Developer Program
> Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated
> accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email
> address(es) of the Publisher account(s).
>
> Google Play Publisher suspensions are associated with developers, and
> may span multiple account registrations and related Google services.
>
> You can visit the Developer Policy Centre to better understand how we
> enforce Developer Program Policies. If you’ve reviewed the policy and
> feel this termination may have been in error, please reach out to our
> policy support team.
>
> Do not attempt to register a new developer account. We will not be
> restoring your account at this time.
>
> The Google Play Team

This was my only developer account to my knowledge. There is a free mp3 app from a friend who asked me to publish it in my account, which I didn’t check properly. I am assuming that created this termination since it happened only after publishing that app. This sudden termination comes as a shock and Google's decision seem very rude to me

Any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "There is a free mp3 app from a friend who asked me to publish it in
>   my account, which I didnt check properly."

You violated Google's policies by uploading an App that you did not have full control over and/or was not developed by you. As well, the App possibly violated Google's policies in terms of violating licensing for code libraries that were included, had code included in the App that was malicious or violated privacy, or was otherwise not compliant with Google's terms.

Google's policies are legal contracts which you agree to when you open an account. You reserve the right to end the contract by deleting your account. They reserve the right to end the contract when their policies are not followed. See https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

> "This sudden termination comes as a shock and Google's decision seem
>   very rude to me."

You may think it is rude, but Google is fully within its rights to terminate your account because you violated their terms. It matters little that you did not get the previous warning emails from Google; you are responsible for monitoring the account email for policy updates.

> *If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this termination may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team.*

Try that; you might attempt to explain that it was honest error on your side.

Comment: Be aware that the last paragraph is an admission that you violated their policies. This basically makes the strategy "I did it, I was an idiot, I'm really sorry, I've learned my lesson and it will never happen again. Please can I have my account back?" Which is probably the best strategy the OP has.

Comment: Good point; that admission should be optional by the OP.

Comment: @DaleM, i did that and i said i made a honest mistake without knowing about it, and i wish to develop my own apps but it does not work like that. I think that error is only applicable to them. If you made an error it means that you deserve your life to be deleted. They should know that a person's life is not 1 or 0. Is this humane to deprive one from his/her right to work? Punishment must be scaled with crime. Fakers always can open new fake accounts to publish software with malware but what about genuine developers made mistake and wish to open new slate?

Comment: @FatihOzcan You breached the contract and they therefore have a right to delete your account. That seems fair to me and even if it isn't - this is contract law: fairness is irrelevant.

Comment: @DaleM, i agree with you on legal and contract basis but i had no idea i was violating their policies. Does panishment have to be with proportionate with crime? I get the same punishment with people delibetelty expoloit them or publish malicius software. First thing comes to mind everyone say they are innocent, but i accept i'm guilty but i had no idea. But there is proof of it on my replies to reviews. I told users to redistribution of a sofwtware is not illegal and they can report me to Google or author of the open coded software. By the way, i published Open Camera apps without any ads.

Comment: @DaleM, I also get one notification email warning me about the violation of spam policy but and another suspention of app would result termination but at the same time i got another for and 1 minute later termination email. This how humans do. You warn someone, give some time to fix issue and if it's fixed you let that person go if he ignores or continues to abuse it again then it's deliberate and you sentence him. My whole life is terminated by bots, i can't get a human response or any advise what i should do. This so depressing. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: This isn't a crime and what Google are doing isn't a punishment - they are simply exercising the right you gave them when you breached the terms you agreed to. It doesn't matter that you didn't know you were breaching them - you are obliged to inform yourself of the terms of every contract you enter. Google has millions of customers who don't break the rules - why should they waste time and resources dealing with the small number who do?

Answer (score -1):

Submit a complaint at Federal Trade Commission https://www.ftc.gov/